# How do I render component in this case ?My method is rendering infinite Components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
function Design() {
  const[designRows,setDesignRows]=useState([])

  const design = useSelector((state) => state.design)
   

      useEffect(()=>{
      for (var i = 0; i < design; i++) {
       setDesignRows([...designRows, <DesignRow key={i} />])
       }
       },[designRows])

return (
   <>
    <section className='mt-5 p-3 w-2/5'>
   <div className=' text-center p-2 h-20 bg-gray-200 font-bold text-lg'>Game Design</div>
    
       <div className='border p-3 mt-6 text-gray-500 font-medium text-sm'>
       
          {designRows.map(data=>(
            <>{data}</>
          ))}
        </div>
     
   </section>
   </>
  )
}

export default Design
```

above program is rendering infinite DesignRow components, I want to render "design" no of components.[design is my global/redux state]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your problem is you are watching for `designRows` state and updating in the same `useEffect`, that is what is causing it to loop infinitely.
I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve, but I guess you want to render n number of  components where n is the length of your design Array, if so you can try :

```
function Design() {
  const [designRows, setDesignRows] = useState([])

  const design = useSelector((state) => state.design)

  return (
    <>
      <section className='mt-5 p-3 w-2/5'>
        <div className=' text-center p-2 h-20 bg-gray-200 font-bold text-lg'>Game Design</div>

        <div className='border p-3 mt-6 text-gray-500 font-medium text-sm'>

          {design.length > 0 && design.map((d, key) => (<DesignRow key={key} />))}
        </div>

      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default Design
```

Comment: design is just integer value, not an array

Comment: btw it solved my problem after I changed a bit of my code, I changed design into an array and pushed DesignRow component into it at every place where I was adding integer to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet will cause an infinite rendering of component because you are updating the value of `designRows in useEffect` and at the same time added it in the dependencies in `useEffect`. To fix this either remove the updating of `designRows` in useEffect or remove the `designRows` from dependency array in `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to this:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
      for (var i = 0; i < design; i++) {
       setDesignRows([...designRows, <DesignRow key={i} />])
       }
 },[design])
```

The second argument is the dependencies - when updated, it triggers the effect.

Comment: rendering only one DesignRow component using this method